# Why do I get AccessViolationException when calling native code from 32-bit comiled version of the app, but not from 64-bit version

Tags: c#, clr, pinvoke

I am calling some C++ native code from my C# managed code. When this dll is loaded from a 64-bit or AnyCPU compiled application, everything works perfectly. When it is loaded from a 32-bit application, I get an AccessViolationException when calling the InitializeSecurityContextW method. The definition of the native method follows:

```
[DllImport(SECUR32DLL, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern StatusEnum InitializeSecurityContextW(
    [In] ref HandleStruct handle1,
    [In] IntPtr handle2,
    [In] String str,
    [In] uint flags1,
    [In] uint reserved1,
    [In] uint flags2,
    [In] IntPtr bufferDesc,
    [In] uint reserved2,
    [In, Out] ref HandleStruct handleOut,
    [In, Out] BufferDescriptor bufferDescOut,
    [Out] out uint flagsOut,
    [Out] out long expiryOut);
```

With the following Structs and enums:

```
public struct HandleStruct
{
    private IntPtr Low;
    private IntPtr High;

    public bool IsZero
    {
        return Low == IntPtr.Zero && High == IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

private enum StatusEnum {
     // Values here.
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
private struct BufferDescriptor
{
    public uint Version;
    public uint Count;
    public IntPtr BufferArray;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
private struct Buffer
{
    public uint Size;
    public uint Type;
    public IntPtr Data;
}
```

And the (simplified) calling code is:

```
Buffer[] bufferOut = new Buffer[1];
bufferOut[0].Size = 0;
bufferOut[0].Type = 2; // Token type
bufferOut[0].Data = IntPtr.Zero; // I'm asking the server to allocate this memory (unmanaged).

GCHandle bufferOutPtr = GCHandle.Alloc(bufferOut, GCHandleType.Pinned);

BufferDescriptor bufferDescOut = new BufferDescriptor();
bufferDescOut.Count = 1;
bufferDescOut.Version = 0; // Version number
bufferDescOut.BufferArray = bufferOutPtr.AddrOfPinnedObject();

uint flags1 = // Some flags here including asking the server to allocate memory;
uint flags2 = 0; //data representation

uint flagsOut;
long expiry;

StatusEnum status = InitializeSecurityContextW(
    ref handle1, // From calling method
    IntPtr.Zero, // Null for this call
    str, // From calling method
    flags1,
    0,
    flags2,
    IntPtr.Zero, // Null for this call
    0,
    ref handleOut, // From calling method, currently handleOut.IsZero == true
    bufferDescOut,
    out flagsOut,
    out expiry);

// Clean up code, never reached.
```

Why is this happening, and why only in 32-bit?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't take into account the fact that 64 bit version *seems* to show no errors. If 32-bit fails with AccessViolationException, either there is a bug in native code, or one or more objects are not pinned correctly. If I had to **hazard a guess** (i.e. I may be way off / wrong), 64-bit may not show the signs simply because address space is so large (by magnitudes), that bug in the code may not trigger an access violation error that easily.

Comment: @VikasGupta Well I've been assuming that's the case. Like the garbage collector is more aggressive about compacting in 32-bit since it has less memory to work with, and it's moving something that isn't pinned, but _happens_ to not get moved in 64-bit. But I can't see what hasn't been pinned that needs to be pinned, can you?

Comment: @VikasGupta Also it can't be that there is a bug in the native code since I also have a native implementation of the same thing which calls the same method directly (using very similar logic) which doesn't fail like this in any case.

Comment: I never had to deal with interops much, so I don't claim to be expert here (only basic knowledge - Hope I could debug my own code, if needed), but you could compare your code for calling InitializeSecurityContextW with the signature and sample code provided on pinvoke.net (reputed site for pinvoke signatures) - http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/secur32.InitializeSecurityContext

Comment: One difference I can see is you have `[In] ref IntPtr bufferDesc,` vs pinvoke.net `IntPtr pInput,`.. i.e. you passing IntPtr **by reference**.. Is that right?

Comment: @VikasGupta Actually, this version of the method used to just be used when bufferDesc was null, i.e. this is the first time we are calling InitializeSecurityContextW. I had another instantiation of InitializeSecurityContextW for calling with a non-null input buffer descriptor. However, based on my answer below I will be removing that instantiation and pinning everything.

Comment: @VikasGupta Also the ref thing is a typo. I'll update my question for future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to pin my output buffer descriptor and pass the address rather than the whole struct.

Comment: Do you mean declaration `ref BufferDescriptor bufferDescOut` vs actual call `bufferDescOut,` Doesn't the compiler complain that you are not passing by ref?

Comment: @VikasGupta No, the invalid looking refs were typos. I've repaired the question to reflect the real situation. Sorry about that.